# Can asynchronous LiveData/Room queries lead to race conditions?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-room, android-livedata

Consider a simple activity containing two fragments:

- `RecordListFragment`: A `RecyclerView` bound to `LiveData<Record>` via a `@Query` and a button which calls a `@Delete` query for a `Record`
- `RecordEditFragment`: Several widgets to change the record and a save button which calls a `@Insert` or `@Update` query for a `Record`

The [documentation for RoomDatabase.Builder#allowMainThreadQueries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#allowmainthreadqueries) states:

> Room ensures that Database is never accessed on the main thread because it may lock the main thread and trigger an ANR. If you need to access the database from the main thread, you should always use async alternatives or manually move the call to a background thread.

Every tutorial/blog/example I found states the same, you should not block the UI thread with database work. My instinct disagrees: There's nothing more I want when inserting or deleting data from a database than having an easy way to block the user from interfering.

If all database access happens on a worker thread one possible order of events that comes to mind is:

1. The user deletes `Record a` on the `RecordListFragment`
2. The user manages to enter the `RecordEditFragment` for `Record a`
3. The background thread executes the deletion
4. The user tries to save/update the non-existent `Record a`
5. Boom

Another scenario is:

1. The user updates an existing `Record a` from the `RecordEditFragment`, transitioning to `RecordListFragment`
2. Before the list has a chance to update the user reenters the `RecordEditFragment` for `Record a`
3. The `RecordEditFragment` opens with old data
4. The background thread executes the save
5. Boom

These are classic race conditions when working asychronously and I cannot imagine that this is actually best practice on Android but I cannot find any documentation that states otherwise. Are these scenarios actually possible or does Android prevent stuff like this from happening? Why not just block the UI for a simple task like inserting a record to not have any possibility of a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can block the user from interfering with tasks without "blocking the UI".

You said:

> There's nothing more I want when inserting or deleting data from a database than having an easy way to block the user from interfering

You can definitely change the UI so that it won't let the user do something while you have background processes or whatever you want running. That is not what "blocking the UI" is. Blocking the UI means blocking the UI **thread** from being able to operate.

Modern Android development, including built in functionality with Kotlin Coroutines, in some ways prevents you from blocking the UI thread by not even compiling until you fix your code. But it's possible that you could be supporting older versions of Android or else not using those language features, so it is still up to you to not write code that will run slowly on the UI thread. This makes it so that your UI seems to be responsive even if the things going on in the other threads might be taking a while.

So, if you need to write to RoomDB or run a network request, that should go on another thread like the IO thread.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads
for more information regarding Android processes and threads (specifically read the sectino about Threads), or for more specific information about how Kotlin Coroutines help check out https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines-adv

Especially, note the following quotes from the Android developer link above:

> When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events ...
>
> ... the Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> Do not block the UI thread
>
> Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

So go ahead and fire off that background work on another thread, and change your UI to show that it's doing something until that other thread completes. Then you have prevented the user from interfering and you've also made the app work in a way that doesn't appear broken.